# Comparing self-equivalences of a triangulated category and automorphisms of its Grothendieck group

Tags: reference-request, ct.category-theory, homotopy-theory, homological-algebra, triangulated-categories

There is a homomorphism from the group of (isomorphism classes of) self-equivalences of a triangulated category to the automorphism group of its Grothendieck group. Is this homomorphism surjective? If not, is there a calculable obstruction? Are there some natural classes of triangulated categories for which it is surjective? In any case, what would be a good reference for this question?

Comment: I might be overlooking something, but isn't the derived category of $\mathbb{P}^1$ already an example where it is not surjective? Tensoring by a line bundle will not give you the automorphism which permutes the copies of $\mathbb{Z}$ in $\mathrm{K}_0(\mathbb{P}^1)$.

Comment: Maybe the OP should ask about self-equivalences that preserve a dualizing object.

Comment: @pbelmans but why is any self-equivalence given by tensoring by a line bundle?

Comment: @JasonStarr well this would be even "less surjective".

Comment: @მამუკა The auto-equivalence group of $\mathbb{P}^1$ consists of standard auto-equivalences: tensoring with a line bundle, pullback along an automorphism, or shifting. Automorphisms induce the identity on the Grothendieck group, shifting is multiplication by $-1$. So that's why I ignored these.

Comment: @pbelmans Is it obvious that automorphisms of P$^1$ induce identity on $K_0$? Also, cannot interchanging $O(1)$ and $O(-1)$ be realized by an autoequivalence?

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე No, because $Hom(\mathcal O(-1),\mathcal O(1))\neq Hom(\mathcal O(1), \mathcal O(-1))$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One obstruction is that if all Hom-sets are finite dimensional vector spaces, and for all objects $X$ and $Y$, $\text{Hom}(X,Y[i])=0$ for all but finitely many $i$, then any self-equivalence must preserve the bilinear form
$$\langle [X],[Y]\rangle =\sum_i(-1)^i\dim\text{Hom}(X,Y[i])$$
on the Grothendieck group.